# Plot a function with different values of a parameter on the same plot

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I want to plot the following function with different values of the parameter $b$:

```
 a = -0.1 Sqrt[0.001^2 + b^2];

 M[t_] := NIntegrate[10w E^(-w/50)((1-Cos[(w+a)t])/(w+a)^2),{w,0,-a,∞}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 100, AccuracyGoal -> 10, Method -> "PrincipalValue"]

 Plot[M[t],{t,0,1000}]
```

How can I code different plots for different values of parameter $b$ in a single plot?

Note: My actual code is pretty bigger than this. So I cannot define a new series of variables and functions for each value of the parameter and then plot them simultaneously.

Comment: `M[t_, b_] := With[{a = -0.1 Sqrt[0.001^2 + b^2]}, (* stuff *)]`, then use `Table[]` within `Plot[]`.

Comment: @J.M Thanks man. But can you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 3):

Following J.M.'s comment (his credit)

```
M[t_, b_] :=  With[{a = -0.1 Sqrt[0.001^2 + b^2]}, 
  NIntegrate[10 w E^(-w/50) ((1 - Cos[(w + a) t])/(w + a)^2), {w, 
    0, -a, ∞}, MaxRecursion -> 100, AccuracyGoal -> 10, 
   Method -> "PrincipalValue"]]
```

Then

```
 Plot[ Table[M[t, b], {b, 1, 2}]//Evaluate, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Suggest you put Evaluate round the table to see the curves in different colours

Comment: its done thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check this formalism. It works.

```
mList = {1, 3, 4, 6};

Plot[Table[m x, {m, mList}] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 10}, 
PlotLegends -> mList]
```